# 3D entity always visible, even when behind another entity

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, qt3d, pyside2

Is there an easy way to show 3D entity at all times, even when that entity is hidden behind another entity? For example, I want that lines are always shown event when they are behind mesh surface.

I use Qt3D framework.

Comment: You should mention in the title of your question that you are looking for answers concerning the Qt3D framework.

Comment: I misread your question and for some reason thought you were asking about how to show the outline of an object even if it is hidden behind other objects. I therefore moved my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568614/how-do-i-draw-the-outline-of-an-object-in-qt3d/52568615

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are talking about the `Qt3D` framework I want to extend the answer of Rabbid76.

To disable depth-testing in the Qt3D framework, add a `QRenderStateSet` to the framegraph branch that renders things (the one that as a `QViewPort` for example) and add a `QDepthTest` to it. Then, set the depth function of the QDepthTest to always. This way, the depth test is always passed and entities in the back will also be drawn, depending on the drawing order. You can use [QSortPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qt3drender-qsortpolicy.html) to adjust the drawing order to back-to-front.

But this won't work when the camera position changes and your entity that you always want to be drawn is in the front. I'd suggest you add another framegraph branch and use a [QLayerFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qlayerfilter.html) to only deactivate depth-testing for this one entity.

If your entity looks weird when deactivating depth-testing (likely for complex objects), you could replace the `QDepthTest` by a `QClearBuffers` and simply clear the depth buffer.

Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818584/2d-meshes-in-qt3d/51839858#51839858), where I showed an example of a custom framegraph with depth test.

Comment: *"and all entities will be drawn, no matter what their z-value is"*. That's only partially true. Entities are only visible in the end when they are drawn in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

If the depth test is disabled, then the geometry (like a line) is always drawn on top of the previously drawn geometry. The depth test can be disabled by:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

See [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml)

---

As an alternative the depth test function, can be set to let a fragment always pass depth test. In Qt this can be done by the class [`QDepthTest`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qdepthtest.html), using the enumerator constant `Qt3DRender::QDepthTest::Always`.

In this case, you have to take care about the order in which the geometry is drawn.
You have to find a way, to render the polygons (opaque geometry) first, by using the depth test function `Qt3DRender::QDepthTest::Less`.
After that you have to render the lines on top, by using the depth test function `Qt3DRender::QDepthTest::Always`.